# Is there a way to stop ode(any) in matlab after a point other than time?

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

Usually any ode like ode23, ode 45 will do the integration from initial time to final time [t0 tf]. Is there a way, the integration can be stopped on some other parameter not dependent on time? For example, I have a linear damper.

```
Initial Pressure p1 = some value
Initial Pressure p2 = some value (not = p1)
time = [t0 tf]
some other constants
options = odeset
y0 = [initial conditions for some parameters containing p1 and p2]
[t,y] = ode45(@func,[t0 tf],y0,options,other constants to carry)

and in func code:
equations for integration for p1 and p2 and some other variables
```

How would it be possible to not run the ode from t0 to tf but stop it when p1 = p2? Or some way I can pre decide the limits for p1 and p2 so that the ode does not exceed them? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is it a computational effort problem, i.e. does it take too long otherwise? You can simply remove the parts of the "regular" solution from the point where p1=p2

Comment: I guess it will take a lot of effort to find and remove the values from the regular solution. Thats why I think I systematic way out of this would be better. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [event](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1017470) option for your ode.

Use

```
opts=odeset('Events',@events);
[t,y]=ode45(@func,[t0 tf],y0,opts);
```

And

```
function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,y)
% check p1 = p2
% and stop
value = y(x1)-y(x2)
isterminal = 1; % stop the integration
direction = 0; % all events
```

Ofc you need to set p1 and p2 first, but I don't know where in your y there are located.

Here is a working example

```
function mytest()
clear T
clear Y
y0 = [1 3];
options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-4, 'AbsTol', [1e-4 1e-4 1e-5], 'Events', @events, 'OutputFcn', @odeplot);
[Tn,Yn,T,Y,I] = ode45(@func, [0 12], [0 1 1], options);
odeplot([],[],'done')
hold on
figure
options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-4, 'AbsTol', [1e-4 1e-4 1e-5], 'OutputFcn', @odeplot);
[Tn,Yn,T,Y,I] = ode45(@func, [0 12], [0 1 1], options);
odeplot([],[],'done')
end


function dy = func(t,y)
dy=zeros(3,1);
dy(1) = y(2)*y(3);
dy(2) = -y(1)*y(3);
dy(3) = -0.51*y(1)*y(2);
end

function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,y)
value = y(1)-y(2);
isterminal = 1; % stop the integration
direction = 0; % all events
end
```

Comment: So this events code should be integrated with the func code that I have to run the computation for ode or should it be a separate code and if separate where do I set the p1 and p2 over here because it should know those values first from the func code in order to see if they are equal or not right? Thanks

Comment: A seperate code, the p1 and p2 sould be somewhere in the y vector.

Comment: No. It did not work. Just the old result coming out.

Comment: function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(tt,xx,Ap,Aorifice,Cd,rho,speed,S)
    % check p1 = p2
    % and stop

    p1 = xx(3,1);
    p2 = xx(4,1);

    if(p1==p2)
        value = 0;
    else
        value = 1;
    end
    isterminal = 1; % stop the integration
    direction = 0; % all events